# Is there a way to suppress child components initialization on condition in angular?

Tags: angular

So what I wanted to do is to have simple conditional wrapper component with template like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition; else falseCondition">
    <ng-content *ngIf="condition"></ng-content>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #falseCondition>
    <div class="div">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p translate="translate" class="text-center">{{message}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

and I wanted to use it like this:

```
<myComponent [condtion]="someCondition" [message]="some message">
     <someOtherComponent [bindings]....></someOtherComponent>
</myComponent>
```

However even if `someCondition` is false and `some message` gets displayed like expected, `someOtherComponent` gets initialized. Is there a way to supress that initialization? I was hoping it will not get created at all if `condition` is false.

It works as expected if I dont use my wrapper component (like below), but plain `*ngIf` with else template - other component is not initialized at all then.

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="someCondition">
         <!-- this works just fine -->
         <someOtherComponent [bindings]....></someOtherComponent>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: try putting `[condition]` inside the `someOtherComponent` and leave the `myComponent` empty. This should destroy your `someOtherComponent` from DOM (and avoid to be initialized), but your `myComponent` will remain in DOM (empty if there's no other stuffs inside). To be more specific need to see your controller where you use @Input() condition

Comment: @LucaTaccagni there is nothing interesting about the conditions. Its just input nothing more. You can put false there as well and it should work

Comment: if you need content projection there's no way to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `myComponent` is not a directive but a component that should have its own template, it cannot prevent its contents from being compiled the same way as `ngIf` directive does.

This can be solved by supplying `<ng-template>` as component contents:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  template: `
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" *ngIf="condition; else falseCondition">
    <ng-content *ngIf="condition"></ng-content>
</ng-container>
...
  `,
})
class MyComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template;
  ...
}
```

And using it like:

```
<myComponent [condtion]="someCondition" [message]="some message">
  <ng-template>
    <someOtherComponent [bindings]....></someOtherComponent>
  </ng-template>
</myComponent>
```

Comment: sorry @estus, but the `<ng-content>` should work as wrapper "before" component html rendering, shouldn't it? maybe switching `<ng-container>` with `<ng-content>` could work..?

Comment: @LucaTaccagni You possibly confused those two. ng-content is a placeholder for contents. The thing that works as wrapper is ng-container. Any way, none of them will prevent someOtherComponent from being compiled at least once. It will be compiled even with empty `template`.

Comment: I am not sure what do you argue about here, but this works like I wanted. I am forcing developer to wrap everythin in ng-template and thats perfectly fine. Inner components gets initialized only if conditions are met. Thanks

Comment: @Antoniossss You're welcome. Since <ng-template> is a necessary here, the alternative is to pass template reference as an input.

Comment: but still it would have to be ng-template am I right? If so, there is no point of moving ng-template outside of component. Its better to keep it inside :) Additonal benefit is that I can now include another template eg for false condition and everything will be wrapped within my components. That is logical and readable approach.